# Very hard integral limit

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, definite-integrals

$$  \lim_{n \to \infty }\int_{0}^{\pi} x^n\sin x \mathrm{d}x$$
I have stumbled across this problem in an old book and havent managed to figure out how to solve it by using basic and intermediate methods. I am a 12th grader. I would appreciate your help!

Comment: If you think about sizes, it should be clear that the thing blows up.

Comment: I understand but I need a more concrete solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Over the interval from $\frac{\pi}{2}$ to $\frac{\pi}{2}+\frac{\pi}{3}$, we have $x^n\ge \left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)^n$, and $\sin x\ge \frac{1}{2}$. Thus our full integral is greater than
$$\frac{\pi}{3}\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)^n\frac{1}{2}.$$
Since $\frac{\pi}{2}\gt 1$, it follows that as $n\to\infty$, the integral blows up.

Comment: I have only one question. Why did you take only a part of the given interval and how can you prove that the interval from 0 to pi/2 doesnt effect the limit.

Comment: The function is non-negative everywhere on the interval $[0,\pi]$ (and mostly positive). So the integrals over the neglected bits, $0$ to $\pi/2$ and $5\pi/6$ to $\pi$, are *positive*. Taking them into account just makes the full integral *bigger*. Since we have shown using an estimate (the displayed expression) that the part from $\pi/2$ to $5\pi/6$ blows up, the whole thing does.  Another way to think of it, the integral is the area under the curve. The area under the part from $\pi/2$ to $5\pi/6$ blows up, so the whole area also does.

Comment: @RazvanParaschiv in essence, everything is positive in this interval. Think of the integral as a summation (a perfectly valid thing to do: it's how integrals are defined!) A summation of all positive things only becomes bigger and remains positive.

Comment: Thank you. A really goos explination and solution.

Answer (score 1):

Another way, using the symmetry of $\sin$:

$$I_n=\int_{0}^{\pi} x^n\sin x \,dx=\int_{0}^{\pi} (\pi-x)^n\sin x \,dx=\int_{0}^{\pi} \frac{x^n+(\pi-x)^n}{2}\sin x \,dx$$

$$\ge \int_{0}^{\pi} \left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)^n\sin x \,dx=2\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)^n\to\infty$$

Answer (score 0):

The antiderivative is
$$\frac 12 i x^{n+1} E_{-n}(-i x)-E_{-n}(i x)+C$$
This makes you definite integral
$$\frac 12 i \pi^{n+1} E_{-n}(-i \pi)-E_{-n}(i \pi)$$
This function is bounded and finite except for $\pi^{n+1}$, which clearly diverges as $n \to \infty$. Thus, we show that the definite integral diverges to infinity. If you want it, [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+x%5En+sin+x) is a WolframAlpha link to the antiderivative

(Note that the antiderivative evaluated at $0$ evaluates to $0$, hence why half of the definite integral disappears)

Comment: I havent studied this method and i dont fully understand it.Thank you for your answer.

Comment: @RazvanParaschiv You actually will have studied everything here, expect for the function $E(x)$ (known as the exponential integral). If you want, just replace $E(x)$ with $\log x$ or something in your head... its the same thing for these purposes, some bounded function. You are right in that the function is more complex... there is no simple antiderivative in terms of functions you meet in a Calc 1 or 2 class. If you want an answer without antiderivatives you can always look at Andre's answer :)

Comment: Thank you for your explination.